# Regex Substitution in Python

Tags: python, regex, timestamp

I have a CSV file with several entries, and each entry has 2 unix timestamp formatted dates.

I have a method called `convert()`, which takes in the timestamp and converts it to `YYYYMMDD`.

Now, since I have 2 timestamps in each line, how would I replace each one with the new value?

EDIT: Just to clarify, I would like to convert each occurrence of the timestamp into the `YYYYMMDD` format. This is what is bugging me, as `re.findall()` returns a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "unix timestamp formatted date" you mean a number of seconds since the epoch. This assumes that every number in the file is a UNIX timestamp. If that isn't the case you'll need to adjust the regex:

```
import re, sys

# your convert function goes here

regex = re.compile(r'(\d+)')
for line in sys.stdin:
  sys.stdout.write(regex.sub(lambda m:
  convert(int(m.group(1))), line))
```

This reads from stdin and calls convert on each number found.

The "trick" here is that `re.sub` can take a function that transforms from a match object into a string. I'm assuming your convert function expects an int and returns a string, so I've used a lambda as an adapter function to grab the first group of the match, convert it to an int, and then pass that resulting int to convert.

Comment: Hmmm... What does the input line where you're hitting that error look like? (You might want to add a `sys.stdout.flush()` call right after the `sys.stdout.write` line while debugging.)

Answer (score 3):

If you know the replacement:

```
p = re.compile( r',\d{8},')
p.sub( ','+someval+',', csvstring )
```

if it's a format change:

```
p = re.compile( r',(\d{4})(\d\d)(\d\d),')
p.sub( r',\3-\2-\1,', csvstring )
```

EDIT: sorry, just realised you said python, modified above

Comment: He said a Unix timestamp, which should be something like 1243326265 (current time). He wants the YYYYMMDD format as output.

Answer (score 1):

Not able to comment your question, but did you take a look at the CSV module of python?
http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-csv

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something along these lines. A lot like Laurence's response but with the timestamp conversion that you requested and takes the filename as a param. This code assumes you are working with recent dates (after 9/9/2001). If you need earlier dates, lower 10 to 9 or less.

```
import re, sys, time

regex = re.compile(r'(\d{10,})')

def convert(unixtime):
  return time.strftime("%Y%m%d", time.gmtime(unixtime))

for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
  sys.stdout.write(regex.sub(lambda m: convert(int(m.group(0))), line))
```

EDIT: Cleaned up the code.

**Sample Input**

```
foo,1234567890,bar,1243310263
cat,1243310263,pants,1234567890
baz,987654321,raz,1
```

**Output**

```
foo,20090213,bar,20090526
cat,20090526,pants,20090213
baz,987654321,raz,1 # not converted (too short to be a recent)
```